# How can I make sound come through both my speaker and headset?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I switch between activities that I want speaker/headphones for many times a day and I don't love the wear and tear this puts on my audio jack (my last two computers have had their front audio jack give out which just makes the situation all the more annoying)

I am wondering if there's a way that I can make my computer output sound through both so I can then handle which one I want sound to come through via the OS and I don't have to touch any cables.

Running Windows 7, my sound chipset is Realtek ALC892.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, applications output sound to one device - however, it is possible to override this, but, this depends on your driver.

I also have an Realtek based audio chipset and this does give me the option - hopefully yours does.

Open the Realtek control panel, click on `Device advanced settings` then click on the option `Make front and rear output devices playback the same audio stream`.

[image]

Comment: What version of the drivers do you have? I just downloaded the latest one and my advanced settings menu has two options as well but the first one says this instead: "Mute the output device, when a front headphone plugged in." - it was checked, but I can't uncheck both it's one or the other.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino I have 6.0.1.6167 - and it is HD Audio (Controller and ALC892 (Codec) according to the Info Button.

Comment: I also have a Realtek chipset and I remember you had to set a value in BIOS in order for the front jacks to be detected. It *will* be motherboard specific (so check it's documentation before) but it might explain what happened to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought for you... I had a headphone jack fall apart on a brand new gateway and I got a usb sound card(?) adapter called Audio Advantage "Micro II" from Turtle Beach. I leave it plugged in to the usb all the time, but if the jack is unplugged from it the sound reverts back to the laptop speakers. I'm not sure, but it might be able to be configured to let both work at the same time. When I called Turtle Beach for tech help they were great about helping out.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else (like me) finds this question...another option is to wire a box that does this for you. With a little electrical/soldering knowledge, you can create a box that has one input and switches between two outputs (or three, or both/none, both/one/none, possibilities are endless). That's how I used to switch between my speakers and headset