# Window 8 x64 bit - Sound does not come through Headphone

Tags: windows-8, audio, headphones

I have installed Windows -8 64 bit about a month ago. Yesterday it shows an unusual behavior. Some time sound come from laptop speaker only after connecting headphone and some time sound comes from both speaker and headphone. I mess up completely as Headphone don't get display on playback devices. When checking from Ubuntu 12.04, headphone and speaker both function normally. I think solution of problem I faced is just opposite as given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/426721/how-can-i-make-sound-come-through-both-my-speaker-and-headset) but didn't work.

System configuration:-
Acer Aspire 4750G, Ram - 4 GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Realtek driver or download latest version for Window 8 from [here](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Audio/Audio_Realtek_6.0.1.6423_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634509739151177500&Step1=Notebook&Step2=Aspire&Step3=Aspire%204752G&OS=712&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=AAP_7). These problem occurs due to the unmatched version of driver with operation system.

Answer (score 0):

Further FYI, not in any way negating previous excellent answer:

Windows 8 added a bunch of code to detect audio plugged-in devices.  For example when plugging external speakers into my laptop, Skype calls voice did not come through.

Following the tip to make headphones the default, mine were greyed out and I couldn't so since I didn't spot a better answer, I had to DELETE my speakers to allow me to set headphones as the default.   I blame Windows 8 for trying to be too smart, but in general am quite satisfied with Windows 8.