# How do I make audio go through both front and rear jacks?

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-10-v1511

My computer has both a front and a rear jack to plug in headphones or speakers. I'm trying to make it so that if I plug a headphone on front and another one on the back, it would ouput sound on both. So in essence, it would allow two people to use headphones without having to buy a splitter.

How do I do this in Windows 10? I managed to make it work on this same computer prior (still Windows 10) but I did a fresh install and now it doesn't work.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/426722/97028) get you close? I know it is for Windows 7, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: I don't have the `Device advanced settings`.